# how to use union for List<anonymousType> and List<Order> in linq

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a `Linq` code as below:

```
var checkList = (from dc in _debtorCreditorService.GetAllDebtorCreditors()
                 join n in _notificationService.GetAllNotification() 
                 on dc.MaturityDate equals n.CreatedDate
                 where n.CreatedDate.Day == today.Day                    
                 select new 
                 { 
                     chek_id = n.TypeId, 
                     date = n.CreatedDate, 
                     title = n.Title 
                 })
                 .Distinct()
                 .ToList();
```

and I have an order list like below:

```
List<Order> order
```

Where this.order properties are `orderId` and `orderDate`

I want to merge these two lists in one list to have `{check_id,date,title,OrderId and OrderDate}` and send that list by JSON to view

Comment: do the two types have the same properties? Show Order. IF they share the same properties then convert you linq to select Order and then Union will work

Comment: You can only union the same types. Does `Order` contain the same properties, in which case use `select new Order { ... }`

Comment: You want to `Union` two different lists(`List<Order>` and a `List<anonymous tpe>`)? What should be the result?

Comment: @Nkosi no,actually the problem is this.order properties are `orderId` and `orderDate`

Comment: @TimSchmelter the result is List<anonymous tpe>

Comment: Then what is the desired out come? You may be using the wrong term. Update question with Order properties and also what the desired outcome should look like.

Comment: @Nkosi i want to merge these two lists in one list to have {check_id,date,title,OrderId and OrderDate} and send that list by `json` to view

Comment: @Mojtaba how are the two objects related. You need to make that clearer in your post. This sounds more like a projection that a union.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*For Making Union Both the side columns name must be same .*

```
// First Collect CheckList
var checkList = (from dc in _debtorCreditorService.GetAllDebtorCreditors()
                 join n in _notificationService.GetAllNotification() 
                 on dc.MaturityDate equals n.CreatedDate
                 where n.CreatedDate.Day == today.Day                    
                 select new Order
                 { 
                     chek_id = n.TypeId, 
                     date = n.CreatedDate, 
                     title = n.Title ,
                     OrderId=0,
                     OrderData=null
                 })
                 .Distinct()
                 .ToList(); 

// Secondly ,Collect Orders
var lstOrder=(from n in Order 
            select new Order
            {
                 chek_id = n.TypeId, 
                 date = n.CreatedDate, 
                 title = n.Title ,
                 OrderId=n.OrderId,
                 OrderData=n.OrderDate
            });

// Finally ,Make Union of both the Table            
var result=checkList.Union(lstOrder).Tolist();
```

Answer (score 2):

> I want to use `Union` for checkList and `List<Order>` but i don't know
>   how. The result should be a  `List<anonymous tpe>`

Well, then it's actually very easy:

```
var orders = orderList.Select(o => new 
                 { 
                     chek_id = o.TypeId, 
                     date = o.CreatedDate, 
                     title = o.Title 
                 });
var resultList = checkList.Union(orders).ToList();
```

This presumes that those properties exist in `Order`, but i'm sure you got the point.

If you only need your first query to "feed" the union you could make it more efficient, the `Distinct` and `ToList` are unnecessary because `Union` removes duplicates.